# Passing a structure handle (converting C to C++ OOP)

Tags: c++, oop, handle

Can you suggest a way how I could pass a "handle (*h)" inside an object? This is how my code looks like in C.

```
int open(const char *name, ini_file_t **);
int read(ini_file_t *h, const char *sn, const char *kn, int *);
int write(ini_file_t *h, char *sn, char *kn, int);
int ini_file_close(ini_file_t *h);
```

I am trying to do this in C++ eliminating the (*h).

```
XTextFile {
public:
int open(const char *name);
int read(const char *sn, const char *kn, int *);
int write(char *sn, char *kn, int);
int ini_file_close();
};
```

Can you share some tips how I could do this?

**Or the question is am I on the right path on doing this in OOP?**

Comment: Just add a `ini_file_t *` attribute to your `XTextFile` class.

Comment: `open` should probably be made a constructor, `close()` a destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my interpretation:

```
class XTextFile
{
    public:
    XTextFile(const std::string& name);// constructor replaces open()
    ~XTextFile();// destructor replaces ini_file_close
    int read(const std::string& sn, const std::string& kn, int *);
    int write(char *sn, char *kn, int);// not sure what these params are but they should also probably be some form of std::string
};
```

C++ constructors are used to initialize an object, and the destructor cleans up its resources when it's free'd. You would use this object like this:

```
void someFunction()
{
    XTextFile txt("c:\\filename.txt");
    txt.read(....);
    // txt is automatically closed when it goes out of scope.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I find this one the most satisfying answer

Answer (score 0):

```
XTextFile {
public:
    int open(const char *name);
    int read(const char *sn, const char *kn, int *);
    int write(char *sn, char *kn, int);
    int ini_file_close();
private:
    ini_file_h * m_handle;
};
```

Of course with that you need to provide a proper constructor to initialize the member to something like 'nullptr'

Answer (score 0):

There is a recognizable pattern here : your `h` is really similar to C++'s `this` pointer. Meaning, you should drop `XTextFile` and make it `XIniFile`, with member functions acting on itself (that's the core of OOP).

Then, to use the full power of the C++, implement RAII : your file should be opened in its constructor, and closed in its destructor. Take some time to design or delete your copy-constructor, assigment operator, and move counterparts if you're using C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `ini_file_t` as a private member variable.

You could replace open() function by constructor. This way:

```
XTextFile {
private:
   ini_file_t* m_h; 
public:
   XTextFile(const char *name);
   ~XTextFile();
   int read(const char *sn, const char *kn, int *);
   int write(char *sn, char *kn, int);
   int ini_file_close();
};
```

Constructor initializes m_h attribute.
You could also use c++ stuff (std::string, std:vector etc.) instead of `char*`